# Redux-form validations not getting caught

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, redux-form

im fairly new to redux.

What im trying to validate is, two key fields cannot hold the same value and all fields are required. For the required part, i am using Field-Level Validations and that seems to work fine. For deciding whether an element already exists, i am using Sync Validation.

1. When the sync validation works, i checked it with console log. It catching the error and adding it to the errors object. But my form is not showing that.. is it not binded? What am i missing here?
2. I have added 'onFocus' and 'onBlur' mouse events to the text-fields, to make then readonly onBlur. They seem to be working fine. But the moment i added that, my `{touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}` error stops getting displayed. What am i doing wrong here?

my form

```
const required = value => (value ? "" : "required")
class CreateObject extends React.Component {

    enableTextField = (e) => {
        document.getElementById(e.target.id).removeAttribute("readonly");
    }

    disableTextField = (e) => {
        document.getElementById(e.target.id).setAttribute("readonly", true);
    }

    renderField = ({ input, label, type, id, meta: { touched, error } }) => (

        <React.Fragment>
            {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}

            <FormControl {...input} type={type} placeholder={label} id={id}
                className={`align-inline object-field-length ${error ? 'error' : ''}`}
                onFocus={this.enableTextField.bind(this)}
                onBlur={this.disableTextField.bind(this)}
            />
        </React.Fragment>
    );

    renderObjects = ({ fields, meta: { touched, error, submitFailed, errors } }) => {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <center>
                        <Button bsStyle="success" onClick={() => fields.push({})}>Add New Object</Button>
                    </center>
                </li>
                {fields.map((object, index) => (
                    <li key={index}>
                        <br />
                        <center>
                            <Field
                                name={`${object}.key`}
                                type='text'
                                component={this.renderField}
                                validate={required}
                                label="Key"
                                id={`${object}.key`}
                            />
                            <div className="divider" />
                            <Field
                                name={`${object}.method`}
                                type='text'
                                component={this.renderField}
                                label="Method"
                                validate={required}
                                id={`${object}.key` + `${object}.method`}
                            />
                            <div className="divider" />
                            <Field
                                name={`${object}.value`}
                                type='text'
                                component={this.renderField}
                                label="Value"
                                validate={required}
                                id={`${object}.key` + `${object}.value`}
                            />
                            <div className="divider" />
                            <span
                                className="align-inline"
                                onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
                                className="allIcons mdi mdi-delete-forever"
                            />

                        </center>
                    </li>
                )

                )}
            </ul>
        );
    }

    submit() {
        //this
    }

    render() {

        const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting, invalid } = this.props;
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.submit.bind(this))}>
                <FieldArray name='objects' component={this.renderObjects} />
                <center>
                    <Button className="align-inline" type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting || invalid}>Submit</Button>
                    <div className="divider" />
                    <Button className="align-inline" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}> Clear All Values </Button>
                </center>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'ObjectRepo',
    validate
})(CreateObject);
```

validate.js

```
const validate = values => {

    const error = {}
    if (!values.objects || !values.objects.length) {
        error.objects = { _error: 'At least one object must be entered' }
    } else {
        const objectArrayErrors = []
        values.objects.forEach((object, objectIndex) => {

            const objectErrors = { _error: 'Object Key should be unique' }
            if (values.objects.filter(item => item.key == object.key).length == 2) {
                objectArrayErrors[objectIndex] = objectErrors
            }
        })
        if (objectArrayErrors.length) {
            error.objects = objectArrayErrors
        }
    }
    console.log(error)
    return error
}

export default validate
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: i guess you must not use onfocus then because already touched have some action

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the code below which works for me. This is your container (or smart component if you wish)

```
export const validateProps = {
  name: [required],
  value: [required, intOrFloat, maxPercent],
  someId: [required],
}

export const transformer = new TypesModel({
  name: String,
  value: Number,
  someId: Number,
})

export default createFormContainer(
  formName,
  'your_form',
  transformer,
  validateProps,
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
  null,
  false,
  null,
  onSuccessSubmit)(YourFormContainer)
```

And the code for types model is

```
class TypesModel {
    constructor(schema) {
        this.schema = schema
    }
    transform(data) {
        const keys = Object.keys(this.schema)
        const result = {}
        for (let index = 0, len = keys.length; index < len; index += 1) {
            const keyName = keys[index]
            try {
                result[keyName] = this.schema[keyName](data[keyName])
            } catch (e) {
                throw new Error(`Type conversion for field "${keyName}" failed`)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}

export default TypesModel
```

You want validators to look like:

```
export const required = value => isEmpty(value) &&
  'Required field'
export const intOrFloat = value => (!isInt(`${value}`) && !isFloat(`${value}`)) &&
    'Must be an integer of float'
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort @Max, but this didnt work for me